# Storing Dates in Oracle via Hibernate

Tags: oracle, hibernate

I'm storing a simple java.util.date in an Oracle XE database via hibernate.

When testing with JUnit if I can retrieve the correct value, I get an error like this:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
  expected:<Sun Dec 28 11:20:27 CET 2008> 
  but was:<2008-12-28 11:20:27.0>
```

The value is stored in an Oracle Date column (which should have a second-precision) which looks okay to me. Also, I'm surprised that 11:20:27 is not equal to 11:20:27.0. Or does this have to do with timezones?

Any help is welcome.

Thorsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, worked some more on it ...

1. Oracle Date columns only store values with an accuracy of a second.
2. Java Dates do contain milliseconds, but they are typically not printed. So

   expected:

was actually created by a date like 11:20:27,345, which is of course not equal to 11:20:27.0

Solution:

- either only use full second dates to store and retrieve
  or
- get hibernate to create the correct Oracle Datatype (TIMESTAMP) - this is very dependent on the dialect specified in the hibernate config (OracleDialect and Oracle10gDialect create different types).

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date` that both represent the same instant in time, `equals(Object)` will return false (it considers two objects of different classes to **never** be equal).

Your tests need to account for that.  The easiest way to do this is to convert the dates to UNIX time (e.g. `java.util.Date.getTime()`) and compare those values.

Comment: Dave, thanks for the idea, but that was not causing the problem.